# AngularJS - json file parse

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble getting to object in json file.

I'm using

```
 .controller("ListController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('../scripts/bbtv.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.artists = data;               
        });
    }])
```

The data gets in the variable, but I can't access any object of it. Here is part of the json file. For example how to print out {{programmeField.titleField.valueField}} ?

```
{
"channelField": [
{
  "displaynameField": [
    {
      "valueField": "bTV"
    }
  ],
  "idField": "BBTV"
}
],
"programmeField": [
{
  "titleField": [
    {
      "langField": "BULG",
      "valueField": "Тази сутрин"
    }
  ],
  "subtitleField": [],
  "creditsField": {
    "moderatorField": [
      "Антон Хекимян"
    ]
  },
  "categoryField": [
    {
      "langField": "BULG",
      "valueField": "Информационно предаване"
    },
    {
      "langField": "BULG",
      "valueField": "Сутрешен блок"
    }
  ],
  "languageField": {
    "valueField": "BULG"
  },
  "lengthField": {
    "unitsField": 1,
    "valueField": "180"
  },
  "videoField": {
    "presentField": "yes",
    "colourField": "yes",
    "aspectField": "4:3",
    "qualityField": "800x600"
  },
  "audioField": {
    "presentField": "yes",
    "stereoField": "no",
    "dolbyDigitalField": "no",
    "dolbySurroundField": "no"
  },
  "startField": "20151216063000 +0200",
  "stopField": "20151216093000 +0200",
  "channelField": "BBTV",
  "clumpidxField": "0/1",
  "_photos": [
    {
      "_id": "5f38a2ab2fedd6b0e48da60b833bb4ddb69d3a1c",
      "_url": "***.jpg",
      "_type": "Letterbox"
    }
  ],
  "_deleted": false,
  "_id": "189397717",
  "_contentId": 45207610,
  "_broadcastdate": "20151216"
}
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `JSON.parse(data)` ?

Comment: I got error when i validated your JSON. Check if your JSON is formed properly.

Comment: JSON is valid, I just cut out part of it for the example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a transport format. Once it's decoded, it's a native data structure, like any other structure. Since you're in JS, use JS conventions, and follow the bracketing/bracing. Note the labelling on the objects/arrays below:

```
data = { "channelField": [
       a                 b
            { "displaynameField": [
            c                     d
                { "valueField": "bTV"
                e
                }
            ],
              "idField": "BBTV"

data.channelField[0].displaynameField[0].valueField -> "bTV"
    a             b c                 d e
```

Comment: Can you help me to loop through and print out all valueField from the json? I am trying to do it with "ng-repeat", but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Since your "programmeField" and "titleField" are array, use programmeField[0].titleField[0].valueField

In future you can copy your json to http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and the click on the Viewer tab.